# Convert image to BMP 24bit with Imagick at PHP

Tags: php, excel, imagemagick

I need insert image to Excel file with Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, so I must convert it to BMP 24-bit. I using code:

```
$preview_file = DIR_CACHE . $productId . '-1.bmp';
$preview = new Imagick(DIR_IMAGE . $row['image']);
$preview->resizeImage(100, 100, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
$preview->setFormat('BMP3');
$preview->writeImage($preview_file);
$worksheet->insertBitmap( $i, $j++, $preview_file, 0, 0, 1, 1 );
```

But in Excel image show bugged. I have tried to resave it with Paint and add to Excel - it became good. So, I have compared both files and see:
[image: Screenshot]

How I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

Link for result BMPs:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17397112/613-1.bmp
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17397112/613-2.bmp

Bug in excel showed as:

[image: Bug]

Comment: Can you give links to the good and the bad images please rather than a hex dump of them?

Comment: Mark, I have uploaded images.

Comment: Sorry, I can't work this out. The difference seems to be the V3 header which is undocumented...https://forums.adobe.com/message/3272950#3272950 The MS Paint file seems to have the Gamma and RGB Chromaticities embedded whereas the ImageMagick version does not. It kind of looks like Microsoft is not disclosing stuff to the outside world yet both their programs (Excel and Paint) are clearly aware of it...